# QMainWindow, Losing QDockWidget Focus In Linux

Tags: c++, qt

### The Problem:

I created a `QMainWindow` with a single `QDockWidget` then detached it from the Main Window and once the Dock Widget loses its focus, it can't get it anymore.

### Reproducible Example Of The Problem:

```cpp
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDockWidget>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QLayout>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  QApplication application(argc, argv);
  QMainWindow *mainWindow = new QMainWindow;
  QDockWidget *dockWidget = new QDockWidget;

  mainWindow->addDockWidget(Qt::LeftDockWidgetArea, dockWidget);
  dockWidget->setWidget(new QWidget);
  dockWidget->setAllowedAreas(Qt::AllDockWidgetAreas);
  dockWidget->widget()->setLayout(new QHBoxLayout);
  dockWidget->widget()->layout()->addWidget(new QLineEdit);
  mainWindow->show();

  application.exec();
}
```

1. After running, detach the dock widget.
2. Do a <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> (Anything that cause lossing focus).
3. Then try again to get the line edit focus.

---

##### Environments:

| OS | Desktop | WM | Qt | Compiler | Project | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Fedora 35 - 5.18.4-101.fc35.x86_64 | KDE | kwin 5.24.4 | 5.15.2 | GCC 11.3.1 20220421 (Red Hat 11.3.1-2) | CMake 3.22.2 | Failed |
| Fedora 32 - 5.7.14-200.fc32.x86_64 | KDE | kwin | 5.14 | GCC 10.2.1 | CMake 3.22.2 | Failed |
| Ubuntu 20.04 focal | GNOME | Metacity WM | 5.14.2 | GCC (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.4.0 | CMake 3.16.4 | Okay |
| Fedora 35 - 5.18.4-101.fc35.x86_64 | GNOME Classic | Mutter 41.7 | 5.15.2 | GCC 11.3.1 20220421 (Red Hat 11.3.1-2) | CMake 3.22.2 | Okay |

Comment: I am not sure if this is will solve the issue, but you need to set a central widget for the mainwindow.

Comment: @alexpdev, Already tried, doesn't work.

Comment: Your code works fine for me on windows using mingw and g++ maybe it's a kde thing